# Append users text input onto the end of a url

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a courier tracking section to a webpage and I want to be able to have a text box so the user can put their tracking number in and then it will add to the end of the URL and load it in a new tab:

`http://wwwapps.ups.com/WebTracking/track?track=yes&trackNums=1Z`

Unfortunately I have no clue where to start so I can't show an example of what I've tried..

Comment: did you try anything may be a piece of code...

Comment: a form with get maybe ........

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: If you have a `<form method="get">` this will be done automatically for you.

Comment: @sMr no, hence "Unfortunately I have no clue where to start so I can't show an example of what I've tried.."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<form  method="get" >
  Look at url after entering order id and submitting 
  <input type="text" name-"trackNumz"/>
  <input type="submit"/>
  </form>
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be adding `name="..."` to your fields, otherwise nothing will be shown in the URL.